# Regex to accept numbers and alphabets in a string but not only alphabets

Tags: regex

I need a regular expression that accepts alphabets and numbers in a text field . If user enters only alphabets or if user enters only numbers then it is not accepted. How can i do this.?

Comment: theres alot of questions on SO regarding regex - search for them using the search bar at the top right

Comment: In what `RegEx` standard?

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal effort in solving the actual problem, including the attempted code and the encountered issues

Answer (score 1):

You could use the regex like below:

```
/^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])[\da-z]+$/i
```

Javascript example:

```
var regex = /^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])[\da-z]+$/i;
console.log(regex.test('aaa')); // false
console.log(regex.test('111')); // false
console.log(regex.test('aaa111')); // true
console.log(regex.test('111aaa')); // true
```

Comment: @user3201640 Show the not working case.

Answer (score 0):

I think someone will write a better regex then this one, but it works:

```
^([a-zA-Z]+\d+[a-zA-Z\d]*)|(\d+[a-zA-Z]+[a-zA-Z\d]*)$
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(\d+[A-Za-z]+)|([A-Za-z]+\d+) should work for you.
"\d" represents a digit which can be out of [0-9].
```

Works perfectly in Java. You can check specifically for any other language or editor.

```
Pass-
  123aaa
  aaa123

Rejects-
  123
  aaa
```

Comment: `\w+` should match `aaa`, `123` and `aa123`. Of the 3, the first 2 are not accepted by the OP.

Comment: Right npinti. Update the post as per you suggestion. Thanks!

Comment: But i want to accept both numbers and alphabets. I dont want only numbers or only alphabets

Comment: Could you please share some example what exactly you want to accept..?

Comment: i want abc123 and 123abc to be accepted. And 123 and abc to be rejected.

Comment: i want abc123 and 123abc to be accepted. And 123 and abc to be rejected

Comment: That's what the regex (\d+[A-Za-z]+)|([A-Za-z]+\d+) is doing. You need to check the Pass and Reject setion. abc123 and 123abc is getting accepted and at the same time 123  and abc are getting rejected.

Answer (score 0):

```
(?i)(?=[a-z0-9]*[0-9])(?=[a-z0-9]*[a-z])[a-z0-9]*
```

Will match a string only if it has at least one number and one letter.

Matches:

```
abc1
123a
```

Does not match:

```
abc
123
```